# Kong request-transformer: Replace URI attribute with header value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, kong, kong-ingress

I am using Kong-transformer to reroute endpoints. however, before i reroute, i want to replace a "variable" in the uri with a header value.

Here's an example:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: request-transformer-header
  namespace: keycloak
config:
  replace:
    uri: "/admin/realms/{realm_name}/users"
plugin: request-transformer
```

this plugin correctly replaces a Icoming from the user to ***"admin/realms/{realm_name}/users"***

However, i want to replace the {realm_name} field with a real realm name that the user provides in the header while doing the request. e.g **"X_realm_name = master"**

Is that possible using Kong request transformer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `headers['X_realm_name']`

lua conf (tested):

```
config = {
  replace = {                   
    uri = "/admin/realms/$(headers['X_realm_name'])/users"                     
  }                               
}
```

yaml (no tested)

```
config:
  replace:
    uri: "/admin/realms/$(headers['X_realm_name'])/users"
```